# OS X programatically enumerate all metadata keys for a given folder

Tags: macos, file, metadata, hfs+

For a given folder on a HFS+ volume on OS X, how do I enumerate all metadata keys (not just the ones used by spotlight/finder, which may be accessed via `xattr` or `mdls`) for a given folder programmatically? Either in Obj-C/Swift or Applescript/bash? I'm unable to find any info on that. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of metadata are you looking for? As far as I know, xattr and mdls cover everything.

Answer (score 0):

I see that "xattr" source is available on GitHub at https://github.com/xattr/xattr/tree/v0.6.2.  It seems to be a combination of C and Python rather than the languages you name but you may be able to deduce the logic.